# Allow Free Users to search Spotify API

Tags: ios, spotify

Hello we have a jukebox style iOS application named "Unifly Music" which uses Spotify API for the source of music. It seems Spotify now requires a premium account to even be able to search and view the catalogue.

Is there any way around this or special access tokens to be requested. Note only a session host actually plays the music. The Session guest simply view catalogue and suggest songs. Allowing more session guest to view catalogue and participate is great marketing to Spotify with no loss. Its a great feeder for Spotify to learn the likes of free users, own their contact information, and later convert those free account holders into premiums.

The spotify web API was updated 5/29/17 which caused the issue for our setup. Please help :) !

Comment: Link to our application if helpful  https://appsto.re/us/msg3R.i

Comment: Just edit additional info into the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Spotify API was indeed changed to require authentication for all calls to the Web API. However, I have good news! The search endpoint is still available to free users! You simply need to follow one of the authorization flows described [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) and include an Authorization header in your call. This change is also reflected in the documentation of the [search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/).

Read the announcement here: https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2017/01/27/removing-unauthenticated-calls-to-the-web-api/